# How can I get the deviceid of the device on which my aplication has got installed?

Tags: iphone, installation

How can I get the device-id of the iPhone on which my application's got installed immediately after installation? Is PUSH_NOTIFICATION the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither your app nor yourself get informed by the OS when your app is installed. You have no option to detect installation unless the user launches the app.

Comment: Thanx Ole.. What is the way to dynamically retrieve the device-id when the user launches the application? Also can I get the notification of uninstallation of my application by any way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code http://www.timeister.com/2009/06/objective-c-get-iphone-device-guid/

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [device uniqueIdentifier];
NSLog(@"Device GUID: %@", uniqueIdentifier);
```